# echo client-server in C - i have an open server that takes strings from different clients - how do i replace the old char[] in new iteration

Tags: c, string

What i'm trying to do is keeping an open server and having different clients send the server a string, the server saves the string in char rcvdmessage[16] and sents it back to the client. I'm new to C and I can't figure out why my code is acting this way

if the first client sends "Hello World", the server sends "Hello World" to the client.
If the second client sends "Bye", on the second iteration, the server will send "Byelo World".

Is there a way to clear out my rcvdmessage[16] at the beginning of each loop? I tried memset[rcvdmessage,0,16] right under the rcvdmessage initialization but then the server sents an empty char array to the client.

```
while(1){

    // accept - creating a new socket for the accepted connection
    addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
    otherfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);
    // if(otherfd == -1){
    //     fprintf(stderr, "failed to accept, error: %d\n", bind_check);
    //     perror("ERROR on accepting");
    //     return 1;
    // } else fprintf(stderr, "success accept, %d\n", bind_check);

    // receive message
    char rcvdmessage[16];
    int bytes_rcvd = recv(otherfd, rcvdmessage, strlen(rcvdmessage), 0);
    // if(bytes_rcvd == -1){
    //     fprintf(stderr, "failed to receive, error: %d\n", bytes_rcvd);
    //     perror("ERROR on receiving");
    // } else{
    //     printf("Rcvd %s, %d bytes\n", rcvdmessage, bytes_rcvd);
    // }

    // send the received message
    int bytes_sent = send(otherfd, rcvdmessage, strlen(rcvdmessage), 0);
    // if(bytes_sent == -1){
    //     fprintf(stderr, "failed to send, error: %d\n", bytes_sent);
    //     perror("ERROR on sending");
    // } else{
    //     printf("Sent %s, %d bytes\n",rcvdmessage, bytes_sent);
    // }
    // memset(rcvdmessage, 0, strlen(rcvdmessage));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function is to get the length of a ***null-terminated*** byte string.

To get the full size of an array you need to use the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator:

```
int bytes_rcvd = recv(otherfd, rcvdmessage, sizeof rcvdmessage, 0);
//                                          ^^^^^^
```

Also note that unless the data sent by your peer is really null-terminated, then using `strlen` in the `send` call is also wrong. Use the size of the received data as given by the `recv` function:

```
int bytes_sent = send(otherfd, rcvdmessage, bytes_rcvd, 0);
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then for your problem, while the above will solve it, you have to remember that uninitialized "automatic" variables (local non-static variables) will remain uninitialized. Their values or contents will be *indeterminate* and seem random.

The correct way to "replace" the local variable inside the loop is what you do, simply define it where you already do. That it seems to contain old data is because of the *indeterminate* part, and happens because the compiler is smart enough to reuse the same memory each iteration.